# How to change a class using a addeventlistener

Tags: javascript

were doing a hanged man and i need to change the color of the keyboard from Blue to grey.

```js
var alphabet = "AZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN";
var keyboard = document.getElementById("game_keyboard");
keyboard.innerHTML = "";
for (var i = 0 ; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
  var letter = alphabet[i];
  var p      = document.createElement("div");
  p.innerHTML = letter;
  p.classList.add("letter");
  p.classList.add("unused");
  keyboard.appendChild(p);
}
```

we have two class, "letter unused" and "letter used". for example of i click on the letter A i needs to change color

Answer (score 1):

You can add event lister for each letter and then after click remove "unused" class and add "used" class.

```js
p.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.target.classList.remove("unused");
    event.target.classList.add("used");
});
keyboard.appendChild(p);
```

Comment: yup, inside the loop, adding event listener to each `p` is the answer